# Transform Laravel Eloquent result

Tags: laravel, eloquent

When I execute this in my Controller

```
$data = User::with('teams')->find(2);
return response(['data' => $data]);
```

I get this as result

```
{
        "id": 2,
        "country_id": 1,
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "created_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
        "updated_at": "2015-02-02 23:08:21",
        "full_name": "John Doe",
        "teams": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Helpdesk medewerker",
                "description": ""
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Retentie",
                "description": ""
            }
        ]
    }
```

Im not interested in the full `teams` data, but only interested in the `teamNames` of the user.

I've done this by adding this

```
$data->each(function($user) {
   $user->team_names = $user->teams->lists('name');
   unset($user->teams);
});
```

I was wondering if this is the correct way of modifying the Eloquent result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an [attribute accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) for that. Add this to your model:

```
protected $hidden = ['teams']; // hide teams relation in JSON output
protected $appends = ['team_names']; // add custom attribute to JSON output

public function getTeamNamesAttribute(){
    return $this->teams->lists('name');
}
```

To change `hidden` and `appends` dynamically you can use the setter methods:

```
$data = User::with('teams')->find(2);
$data->setHidden(['teams']);
```

Comment: Then it would hide from every User object where I load the teams relation

Comment: That's correct. You could use `setHidden()` and `setAppends()` to change those dynamically

Comment: Could you show this in your answer? I'm not sure where I would call the setHidden() then. In my Eloquent query or so?

Comment: Thanks, smart solution!

Answer (score 0):

Filter out the columns you want in your first build.

```
$data = User::with(['teams' => function($query){
    return $query->select('name');
}])->find(2);
```

Will output:

```
{
    ...
    "teams": [
        {
            "name": "Helpdesk medewerker"
        },
        {
            "name": "Retentie"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can also use the `lists` method.

```
$data = User::with(['teams' => function($query){
    return $query->lists('name');
}])->find(2);
```

Will output:

```
{
    ...
    "teams": ["Helpdesk medewerker", "Retentie"]
}
```